# How to create FULL TEXT index using spring data JPA?

Tags: jpa, indexing

As you know, in spring data JPA, we can use @Table(indexes) to create indexes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "name_idx", columnList = "name", unique = false) })
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
    private String name;

    '''other columns and methods'''

}
```

But it seems that we can't specify the index type, so is there a solution that we specify one column to a FULLTEXT index?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have found a workaround, you can use the columnDefinition parameter of the @Column annotation to add a FULLTEXT KEY. It's not a perfect solution, but i think it's okay as a workaround.

```
@Column(name = "url", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL, FULLTEXT KEY urlFulltext (url)")
private String url;
```

best regards

Thorben